# Read log file and get lines in columns instead of rows

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, logging

have a log file and want to read the lines into single line columns for Excel.
Currently they are stacked in rows. i want to stack the 3 lines into one line in reverse  3>2>1

```
FOR /F "delims=~" %%a in (svn.log)  echo %%a  
set col3 = %%a 
echo col3 col2 col1
```

Is there a easy way to do this?

Input Log: >>>>

```
LINE#1 >r132852 | USERID | 2014-05-14 11:57:38 -0700 (Wed, 14 May 2014) | 3 lines
LINE#2 >>>Changed paths:
   M /Customer/lag/inilib/ASIPS_4600.ini
   M /Customer/lag/inilib/ASIPS_4600_TEXT_SEARCH.ini

LINE#3>> Connections tab in Plan Authoring and WO Execution.
LINE#4>> Ques ID: QUES-806
```

Output Log: >>>

```
LINE#4>> Ques ID: QUES-806 LINE#1 >>> r132852 | USERID | 2014-05-14 11:57:38 -0700 (Wed, 14 May 2014) | 3 lines LINE#2 >>>>Changed paths: M /Customer/lag/inilib/ASIPS_4600.ini M /Customer/lag/inilib/ASIPS_4600_TEXT_SEARCH.ini LINE#3 >>> Connections tab in Plan Authoring and WO Execution. ***
```

the output should be in 1 straight line in columns

```
Input log:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r132994 | Userid | 2014-05-19 06:22:51 -0700 (Mon, 19 May 2014) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
M /Customer/Company/IPS/lag/message/ASIPSI_MISSING_PAGE.sql
M /Customer/Company/IPS/lag/message/ASIPSI_MISSING_WORK_ORDER.sql
M /Customer/Company/IPS/lag/message/ASIPSI_MISSING_WORK_PLAN.sql

Added messages in try catch to display to the user in case objects do not exist any longer
Ques ID: ASIPS-1003
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r132960 | Userid | 2014-05-17 03:18:09 -0700 (Sat, 17 May 2014) | 3 lines
Changed paths:

modified the command on the product Nodes tab to display either the WO or the page
Ques ID: ASIPS-1003
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r132879 | Userid | 2014-05-15 01:18:32 -0700 (Thu, 15 May 2014) | 4 lines
Changed paths:
M /Customer/Company/IPS/lag/udvlib/ASIPSI_541CA51A7CCB439FB318B8482E380F78.sql

I have forgotten to remove the two buttons I have created for the merge PDF demo. 

Ques ID: ASIPS-1003
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r132878 | Userid | 2014-05-15 01:05:10 -0700 (Thu, 15 May 2014) | 4 lines
Changed paths:
 M /Customer/Company/IPS/lag/udvlib/ASIPSI_541CA51A7CCB439FB318B8482E380F78.sql

Correction of the Tag property for button [Display Object].

Ques ID: ASIPS-1003
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r132834 | Userid | 2014-05-14 09:05:13 -0700 (Wed, 14 May 2014) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
M /Customer/Company/IPS/lag/udvlib/ASIPSI_541CA51A7CCB439FB318B8482E380F78.sql

Display Object in Tab Page Nodes doesn’t display the work order when node type is KO.
Ques ID: ASIPS-1003
```

Output required:

```
Ques ID: ASIPS-1003,  
r132994 | Userid | 2014-05-19 06:22:51 -0700 (Mon, 19 May 2014) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
M /Customer/Company/IPS/lag/message/ASIPSI_MISSING_PAGE.sql
M /Customer/Company/IPS/lag/message/ASIPSI_MISSING_WORK_ORDER.sql
M /Customer/Company/IPS/lag/message/ASIPSI_MISSING_WORK_PLAN.sql

Added messages in try catch to display to the user in case objects do not exist any longer
------------------------------------------------------------ 
-------------------------------
```

Each line starting with QUES should be one line across in the CSV file like before only there are multiple revisions and QUES ID's

Comment: Give an example of the input and output

Comment: Description updated with log Line#

Comment: The editor does not let me create 1 line as in Excel. I edited description. echo Line#4 LINE#1 LINE#2 LINE#3

Comment: I want to reorder the lines in the FOR LOOP  for Excel report so that they will go into Excel spreadsheet based on ID#  first which is Line#4. Currently line#4 comes out last but in a row not one line. Instead of UP/DOWN i want one line across in the order we want to chose with ID first, Revision, Description etc

Comment: How many lines are in the file?  Always 4?

Comment: Yes there will be always be 4 with the query that is used

Comment: Your new input log/output log data doesn't seem to match,  For example your output log has `132852` but it is not in your input log. Just a tip when you edit your question - paste the data from your file and then highlight it in the editor and click `{ }` which adds 4 spaces to the start of every line.  Just ensure that a blank line is above and below, and it will appear properly in the post - with very long lines where it is supposed to have very long lines.

Comment: The output log is just a example/sample  of what i would like the output to look like (required output was the heading) I was the hoping script will take any data and place in one line per revision. The script needs to format the input log and place the output of the  revision in  one line format as before. The data will change per revision look up.

Comment: Can we add attachments in text file?

Comment: Nothing else has changed except that there can be more than 4 lines in the input. The output log sample cannot be edited into one line. It wraps in the editor. The sample script you gave before only works if there are 4 lines in the log. If there are more than 4 lines it wraps and does not include the multiple revisions. I updated the output log since it was just a sample. The main issue is taking the input log multiple revisions and making a revision in one line

Comment: You can provide a link to a zip file on any web space, with an input file and output file inside.  The lines wrap in the editor but when you commit the post they display as they should.  The reason why an exact sample is needed is so that the task is crystal clear and there are no misunderstandings.

Comment: I have updated the output log in the description. Only 1 revison shows and an extra line since there are multiple revisions

Comment: Here are links to output & input:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/vagfdr4foowsegf/output.csv     https://www.dropbox.com/s/59l7njeehsrg5p3/svn.log

Comment: The original code in my answer creates the same output file.  You seemed to be saying that you wanted a different output file.

Comment: Yes. Since there are 5 Revisions in input log,we need all of the lines for each revision in one line format. So 5 lines in the output.csv    If the user search by QUES ID then all 5 revisions need to be there not just the first revision.  Ques ID: ASIPS-1003  has 5 revisions and there should be 5 lines in output.csv

Comment: My original code answered your question and that's the point of Stack Overflow.  if you want to change the question then you are supposed to open a new question.  In either case this has been confused because you haven't shown the kind of input files that can be found, and also what you want in the resulting file.  Your original attempts at showing the input and output included text and spaces which were not in the files - and only you knew which bits were added and which bits weren't.  So open a new question, supply a link to a zip file with input and output files, and the task may be clear.

Comment: Ok i opened a new question and put this one as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this on a sample file:

```
@echo off
< svn.log (
set /p a=
set /p b=
set /p c=
set /p d=
)

for %%a in ("%d%,%c%,%b%,%a%") do >newfile.csv echo %%~a
pause
```

Comment: I ran into a problem where there were multiple revisions for one ID. So there will be more than just 4 lines. Is there a way to read  all the lines and leave off the line delimeter "-" which will be in the begining and ending of multiple line revisions. Then pipe the lines as the original code

Comment: A sample of the output would be useful to see what you mean. You can edit your question and add it.

Comment: I have added sample Input log and Output  in the description. Thanks